# meaning of "braced for more sobbing"

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature, verb-usage

This passage is from *The Children's Bach* by Helen Garner

> someone laughed up high, there was a scuffling somewhere in the house,
> Dexter was up, he would see to it. Her muscles let go and she was away.
>
> Someone was whispering above her head, through the window, tap tap
> tap on glass, calling her name. Her feet hit the floor and her finger the lamp
> switch before her eyes were open. ‘What? What?’
>
> ‘Come and open the front door, Thena! It’s me!’
>
> ‘What on earth are you doing?’ Dexter was standing on the front
> verandah in his pyjamas with both hands clapped over his mouth and his
> eyes rolling. He scampered past her and dived on to the bed.
>
> ‘He had her up against the fridge!’ he snorted. He giggled and thrashed
> his legs like a naughty boy in a dormitory. ‘I was on my way to the lavatory.
> I turned on the kitchen light and they were –’
>
> ‘Who?’ She pushed the bedroom door to and flicked off the light.
>
> ‘Him! The one with the tattoo!is in the kitchen!’
>
> ‘What? Is Elizabeth here!’
>
> ‘No! It was Vicki! I had to come back round the outside of the house.
> They must have thought I was perving on them.’ He took a big quivering
> breath. ‘Is there going to be a scandal?’
>
> ‘Isn’t she a little monkey,’ said Athena. ‘I hope she’s on the pill.’ She lay
> down, smiling to herself. The curtain moved on the air, settled, moved
> again. It was like waiting for a play to continue.
>
> An engine slowed down outside, a taxi radio quacked, a door slammed,
> heels clacked to the verandah as smartly as if it were broad day.
>
> ‘Here’s your scandal,’ said Athena.
>
> They lay flinching on the bed. Her knocking shook the house. The
> neighbour’s dog began to bark.
>
> ‘Open the door,’ said Athena. ‘She’ll wake the kids.’
>
> He scrambled into the hall. Elizabeth pushed past him and charged down
> the hall towards Vicki’s room.
>
> ‘The back door wasn’t locked, Morty,’ Dexter sang out after her. ‘She’ll
> think it’s our fault,’ he hissed to Athena.
>
> ‘Don’t be silly. Let them sort it out for themselves.’ She turned her back
> to him and he flung his arm around her.
>
> ‘**This is awful**!’ he said.
>
> ‘**This must be what people do**,’ said Athena. ‘Go to sleep.’
>
> Dexter lay rigid as a board, **braced for more sobbing**, but Athena slept.

brace (for something) mean: to mentally or physically prepare yourself or someone else for something unpleasant that is going to happen.

Does here "braced for more sobbing" mean: Dexter is mentally preparing himself to hear someone's sobbing? (maybe Vicki is sobbing)

And in the dialogue:

> ‘This is awful!’ he said.
>
> ‘This must be what people do,’ said Athena. ‘Go to sleep.’

Does "This is awful" refer to the act between the man with tattoo and Vicki and Athena say that people act like them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He "braced for more sobbing" means that he is getting ready to hear more sobbing. Since sobbing wasn't mentioned in this extract, there's no way to tell what was referred to.  (A search didn't show the text online.)
As to what is awful, that is probably the whole situation, more than just the goings on between Vicki and her paramour.

Comment: Lots of thanks, And when Athena says "This must be what people do" does it mean literally, I do not get its meaning clearly, I thought maybe it is an expression, do you have any idea?

Comment: Perhaps she is not used to situations like this, and supposes that it is how (other) people behave in such circumstances.

Comment: It's a strange comment, almost as if Athena were a foreigner or a non-human alien. But, without reading more context, who knows.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think I included sufficient context, the other parts did not related to this part. as a non-native I get confused by this comment and I did not expect negative point! –

Comment: @ViserHashemi (I did not give you a negative point.) What I meant by my last comment was simply that "this is what people do" sounds as if she is not identifying with the people she is talking about.